# Can't access fields of the abstract class instances in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, field, abstract-class

I'm trying to build an FPS game in unity, and I'm trying to implement weapon equipment by a character.
For this, I have:

- a public abstract Weapon class
- a MachineGun class inheriting from Weapon.cs
- a Character class, with an array of equipped weapons

Weapon class:

```
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour { 
    lots of weapon code
}
```

Machinegun class:

```
public class MachineGun : Weapon{
    lots of machinegun code
}
```

In the Character class, I do this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//keeps track of all the character properties
public class Character : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject[] _equipedWeapons = new GameObject[10];     //an array of all the weapons a character has

private void Start()
{
    _equipedWeapons = new GameObject[10];                               //size of the weapons array, TEMP 10
    _equipedWeapons[0] = new GameObject();
    _equipedWeapons[0] = GameObject.FindWithTag("Weapon0");
}
```

**and this is where my problem is:**

```
public void IncreaseBullets(int amount)
{
    _equipedWeapons[0].;
}
```

**I can't seem to access the amount of bullets this machinegun has.
In fact, I can't access it's own machinegun fields, OR the inherited weapon fields.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you attached the MachineGun Script to the GameObject.
You are trying to access the GameObject properties. What you have to do is to get the MachineGun Script first.

```
MachineGun weaponScript = _equipedWeapons[0].GetComponent<MachineGun>();
weaponScript.
```

You can also get the Weapon Script like this. When you want to access different weapon types in the same method.

```
Weapon weaponScript = _equipedWeapons[0].GetComponent<Weapon>();
weaponScript.
```

Comment: You're right, I tried to get to the GameObject instead of accessing the script attached to the GameObject.
Thanks!

It's still kind of confusing though, why aren't the fields of the game object accessible when they are public instantiated in the machinegun script attached to the gameobject?

Comment: Because a `GameObject` can have multiple `Components`. For example a `GameObject` with `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` attached. Both components can have a public variable `counter` - now `GameObject.counter ` is not clear.

Comment: @Thrindil Your Script cannot know if you attached a Weapon Script to a specific GameObject. This is why you have to tell it, that there is a Component of type Weapon. The GameObjects you build in the Unity Editor and the attached Components are separated from your C# Code